# pushState - Remove parent directory from href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate

This is my code:

```
$("a").on("click", function(event) {

    var refrence = $(this).attr("href");
    window.history.pushState( {}, "", refrence );
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Now if I click on an anchor first time, let's say it's href is: http://example.com/pages/about ,

URL changes correctly; But if I click on this anchor next time: http://example.com/pages/contact ,

URL on browser will become: http://example.com/pages/pages/contact ,

You see **/pages** directory didn't clear first time from URL. How can i resolve this problem?

Edit:

```
<a href="pages/about.html" class="ajax">About</a>
<a href="pages/contact.html" class="ajax">Contact</a>
```

This is HTML i'm dealing with.

```
//  ajax
var $main = $("main");

$(".ajax").on("click", function(event) {

    var refrence = $(this).prop("href");
    var myAjax = function() {
        $main.load(refrence);
    };
    window.history.pushState(myAjax(), "", refrence);

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

And this is JS full function i'm using.

Also i work on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute URLs like `/pages/about.html` (with leading slash) instead of relative URLs like `pages/about.html` or provide a [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element like `<base href="/">`.

Otherwise, once navigated (either by going to link statically or by using `history.pushState()` in JS), relative links are resolved based on the updated current directory (`/pages/` + `pages/about.html` = `/pages/pages/about.html`, etc.).

Comment: I have checked your solution but It didn't work. For sure I did **console.log(refrence)** , I can see this URL is absolute as you have said it should be but absolute path is wrong. This is Second log: http://example.com/pages/pages/contact

Comment: Then please provide your HTML code that contains the link (`A` element) you are dealing with.

Comment: Hi Marat. I have Edited my post. Thanks

Comment: As expected, your issue is related to relative paths, just differently. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Really thanks Marat. I will try your solution with _base_ element and write the result here.